# Problem with Julia variable name \theta\dot in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

I would like to have a variable named theta with a dot above the theta.

In VS Code with the julia extension, I type the variable name as \theta\dot. I get theta with a dot, but the dot is off to the right side, not above the theta. If I try to do this with x instead of theta by entering x\dot, the dot appears above the x, as it should.
Does anyone know how to fix this? Is there a better IDE that VS Code for Julia?

Comment: Probably a font issue rather than IDE issue. Just looking at the character, there's not a lot of room for the dot if it were centered. VS Code is the preferred editor, anyway.

Comment: Agree with @NickBauer this is definitely a font issue - I see it above theta in my font.